# CheckBox in CustomAdapter for ListView

Tags: android, listview

Ive got a `ListView` with a custom Adapter. now I added a CheckBox to every element to get a "multiple check listview" but with the following code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    String doubleTab = "\t\t";
    CheckBox elementChecker;
    ArrayList<Boolean> isChecked;

    ArrayList<Integer> checkedPositions = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public CustomListAdapter(Context context, String[] dataListFinal) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item_datalist ,dataListFinal);
    }
    public String allElementsAdapter = "";

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater iteminflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View customView = iteminflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_datalist, parent, false);

        ImageView image = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.list_icon_product);
        TextView textViewlabel = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_datalist_label_textview);
        TextView textViewdetails1 = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_datalist_textview_details_1);
        elementChecker = (CheckBox) customView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox_Item);

        String singleListItem = getItem(position);
        String[] singleListItemArray = singleListItem.split("\t");
        String id = singleListItemArray[0];
        String product = singleListItemArray[1];
        String label = singleListItemArray[2];



        allElementsAdapter = product + label + serial + mac + daaid + bill;

        switch (product) {
            case "Pc":
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_pc_circle);
                break;
            case "Laptop":
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_laptop_circle);
                break;

        }

        String details1 = product;

        textViewlabel.setText(label);
        textViewdetails1.setText(details1);

        elementChecker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (elementChecker.isChecked()){
                    Log.d("SELECTED", "yes");
                }else {
                    Log.d("SELECTED", "no");
                }
            }
        });

        return customView;
    }

    public String getAllElements(){
        return allElementsAdapter;
    }

}
```

The `OnClickListener` only watches the last entry. Can somebody help me and explain what I have to to?

Comment: what do you mean by "The OnClickListener only watches the last entry"

Comment: declare CheckBox elementChecker; inside getView

Comment: But what is the problem, you are facing, you have not said?

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain If I check/decheck one of the elements I only get the log message for the last element. If the last one is dechecked the log entry always says : "SELECTED no" If it is checked it is always : " SELECTED yes" no matter if I check or decheck another element

Comment: declare Checbox inside the getView method. it is initiazing empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare `CheckBox elementChecker;` inside getView

Comment: wow Dude thats it! But can you tell me why? Is it because in my "version" The checkbox is not created for every element?

Answer (score 1):

You always overwrite your `elementChecker`

```
    Checkbox elementChecker = (CheckBox) customView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox_Item);
```

would be a solution. But you'll have to save the state of your checkboxes somewhere...

Comment: That is the next step ;)